# Unboxing boxed value in vector of four tuples

Tags: performance, haskell, vector, ghc, unboxing

There is a performance issue I am trying to debug as part of a more complicated code. It seems that `append` function that I am using to create a dynamic, growable vector of `(Int,Int,Int,Int)` is causing one of the `Int` in the tuple to be boxed and unboxed before being written to the vector. I wrote a simpler code that reproduces the issue - it seems to happen only when I add the vector growth functionality in `append` function - sample code below (it doesn't do much useful work except reproducing the issue), followed by snippets of `core` which show the value being boxed and unboxed:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Test
where
import Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as MU
import Data.Vector.Unboxed as U hiding (mapM_)
import Control.Monad.ST as ST
import Control.Monad.Primitive (PrimState)
import Control.Monad (when)
import GHC.Float.RealFracMethods (int2Float)
import Data.STRef (newSTRef, writeSTRef, readSTRef)
import Data.Word

type MVI1 s  = MVector (PrimState (ST s)) Int
type MVI4 s  = MVector (PrimState (ST s)) (Int,Int,Int,Int)
data Snakev s = S {-# UNPACK #-}!Int
                                !(MVI4 s)

newVI1 :: Int -> Int -> ST s (MVI1 s)
newVI1 n x = do
          a <- new n
          mapM_ (\i -> MU.unsafeWrite a i x) [0..n-1]
          return a

-- Growable array - we always append an element. It grows by factor of 1.5 if more capacity is needed
append :: Snakev s -> (Int,Int,Int,Int) -> ST s (Snakev s)
append (S i v) x = do
   if i < MU.length v then MU.unsafeWrite v i x >> return (S (i+1) v)
   else MU.unsafeGrow v (floor $! 1.5 * (int2Float $ MU.length v)) >>= (\y -> MU.unsafeWrite y i x >> return (S (i+1) y))

gridWalk :: Vector Word8 -> Vector Word8 -> MVI1 s -> MVI1 s -> Snakev s -> Int -> (Vector Word8 -> Vector Word8 -> Int -> Int ->      Int) -> ST s (Snakev s)
gridWalk a b fp snodes snakesv !k cmp = do
   let offset = 1+U.length a
       xp = offset-k
   snodep <- MU.unsafeRead snodes xp -- get the index of previous snake node in snakev array
   append snakesv (snodep,xp,xp,xp)
{-#INLINABLE gridWalk #-}
```

GHC generates a version of `append` for use in `gridWalk`. That function is `$wa` in the core - Please note the boxed Int argument:

```
$wa
  :: forall s.
     Int#
     -> MVI4 s
     -> Int#
     -> Int#
     -> Int#
     -> Int  ======= Boxed value - one of (Int,Int,Int,Int) is boxed
     -> State# s
     -> (# State# s, Snakev s #)
$wa =
  \ (@ s)
    (ww :: Int#)
    (ww1 :: MVI4 s)
    (ww2 :: Int#)
    (ww3 :: Int#)
    (ww4 :: Int#)
    (ww5 :: Int) === Boxed value
    (w :: State# s) ->

....
....
of ipv12 { __DEFAULT ->
              case (writeIntArray# ipv7 ww ww4 (ipv12 `cast` ...)) `cast` ...
              of ipv13 { __DEFAULT ->
              (# case ww5 of _ { I# x# ->
                 (writeIntArray# ipv10 ww x# (ipv13 `cast` ...)) `cast` ...
                 },
                 S (+# ww 1)
                   ((MV_4
                       (+# y rb)
                       ==== x below unboxed from arg ww5 ======
                       ((MVector 0 x ipv1) `cast` ...) 
                       ((MVector 0 x1 ipv4) `cast` ...)
                       ((MVector 0 x2 ipv7) `cast` ...)
                       ((MVector 0 x3 ipv10) `cast` ...))
                    `cast` ...) #)
```

`gridWalk` boxes the value when calling `append`:

```
=== function called by gridWalk ======
a :: forall s.
     Vector Word8
     -> Vector Word8
     -> MVI1 s
     -> MVI1 s
     -> Snakev s
     -> Int
     -> (Vector Word8 -> Vector Word8 -> Int -> Int -> Int)
     -> State# s
     -> (# State# s, Snakev s #)
a =
  \ (@ s)
    (a1 :: Vector Word8)
    _
    _
    (snodes :: MVI1 s)
    (snakesv :: Snakev s)
    (k :: Int)
    _
    (eta :: State# s) ->
    case k of _ { I# ipv ->
    case snodes `cast` ... of _ { MVector rb _ rb2 ->
    case a1 `cast` ... of _ { Vector _ rb4 _ ->
    let {
      y :: Int#
      y = -# (+# 1 rb4) ipv } in
    case readIntArray# rb2 (+# rb y) (eta `cast` ...)
    of _ { (# ipv1, ipv2 #) ->
    case snakesv of _ { S ww ww1 ->
    ====== y boxed below before append called ======
    $wa ww ww1 ipv2 y y (I# y) (ipv1 `cast` ...) 
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

So, the effect seems to be boxing of value in `gridWalk` and unboxing in `append` before insertion into the vector of `(Int,Int,Int,Int)`. Marking `append` `INLINE` doesn't change the behavior - those boxed values just move in the function body of `gridWalk`.

I will appreciate pointers on how to make this value unboxed. I will like to keep the functionality of `append` (i.e., handle vector growth when capacity is exceeded) while refactoring it.

`GHC` version is `7.6.1`. Vector version is `0.10`.

Comment: I don't know why it's boxed, and I'm not trying to find out at this time of night and beer, but `append (S i v) !x@(_,_,_,!_) = ...` gets the last unboxed too. Looks definitely fishy, however, might be worth opening a ticket.

Comment: @DanielFischer, yes, you are right about unboxing with strict pattern. I will get a simpler case to reproduce for GHC trac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a comment.  I figured I would get rid of the tuple argument (adjusting the use of `append` in `gridWalk`), but the result is that (only) the last Int argument has to be bang'd to get everything unboxed, which does seem strange:

```
append :: Snakev s -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> ST s (Snakev s)
append (S i v) a b c !d = do
   if i < len then do MU.unsafeWrite v i (a,b,c,d)
                      return $ S (i+1) v
              else do y <- MU.unsafeGrow v additional        
                      MU.unsafeWrite y i (a,b,c,d) 
                      return $ S (i+1) y
  where len = MU.length v           
        additional = floor (1.5 * int2Float len) -- this seems kind of bizarre 
                                        -- by the way; can't you stay inside Int?
                                        --  3 * (len `div` 2) or something
```

---

Edit, also, you get everything unboxed if you move the application of `S (i+1)` outside the do block, but I'm not sure if that gets us closer to the quarry...:

```
append :: Snakev s -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> ST s (Snakev s)
append (S i v) a b c d = do
       if i < len then liftM (S (i+1)) $ do MU.unsafeWrite v i (a,b,c,d)
                                            return v
                  else liftM ( S (i+1)) $ do y <- MU.unsafeGrow v zzz         
                                             MU.unsafeWrite y i (a,b,c,d) 
                                             return  y
      where len = MU.length v           
            zzz = floor (1.5 * int2Float len)
```

But if `liftM` is replaced by `fmap` we are back to the lone unboxed in.  Things go well if `liftM (S (1+i)` *or* `fmap (S (i+1)` is moved all the way out to the front:

```
append (S i v) a b c d = S (i+1) <$> do ...
```

Comment: yep, forcing bang in the tuple pattern too fixes the issue. I will file a ticket to see what GHC HQ says.

Comment: thanks for heads up. I have filed a bug ticket for vector library. Accepting your comment as answer because of liftM workaround.

Comment: @marc_s, "quarry" here refers poetically to an aim being pursued, as an animal hunted. It is not an error.